# What is the format of the RRData argument of dnscmd /RecordAdd for TXT records?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows, txt-record, windows-dns

The format for a TXT record is:

```
owner TTL class TXT text_string
```

The documentation for dnscmd.exe gives the following syntax for the \recordadd command:

```
dnscmd [<ServerName>] /recordadd <ZoneName> <NodeName> <RRType> <RRData>
```

for /recorddelete it is almost identical with the optional `[/f]` flag

```
dnscmd <ServerName> /recorddelete <ZoneName> <NodeName> <RRType> <RRData>[/f]
```

For RRType TXT RRData has the following syntax.

```
<string> [<string>]
```

I cannot find an explanation or clear examples of usage

How do these two parameters map to the text_string in the TXT record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the usage text for the TXT `<RRType>` suggests:

```
    TXT             <String> [<String>]
```

The valid input data for `<RRData>` is one or more strings. If you input several strings, dnscmd will add a single record with a comma-seperated list of the strings you put in as it's value.

So

```
dnscmd /recordadd contoso.com. mytxt TXT this is the value
```

will result in the following TXT record:

```
mytext.contoso.com.  [TTL]  IN  TXT  "this, is, the, value"
```

---

If you need to input a string with spaces as a single string value, just enclose it with `""`:

```
dnscmd /recordadd contoso.com. mytxt TXT "this is the value"
```

which will result in:

```
mytext.contoso.com.  [TTL]  IN  TXT  "this is the value"
```

Comment: Much thanks. Just to be clear I am not misunderstanding. Are you saying the usage text suggests a single record with a comma separated list, or just that the valid input data is one or more strings?

Comment: The usage text just suggests that multiple strings is considered valid input data (which it is, although the result is not that intuitive)

Comment: @Mr.Mindor If the answer provided the details you needed, please accept the answer as a solution so it doesn't figure as "unanswered" :-)